# How to do a SMW query based on the current year/month/etc.?

Tags: semantic-mediawiki

I'd like to perform a SMW query based on current year and month information. The problem: It seems that I need to feed values into the SMW ask section in a non-static way as I cannot hard code these values. How can I do that and perform such a query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`{{#time:}}` parser function](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Help:Extension:ParserFunctions##time). Date formats that SMW will understand are given [here](https://www.semantic-mediawiki.org/wiki/Help:Type_Date#Input_examples). Below, I used `d.m.Y` and `d xg Y` that will definitely work in a wiki in Russian.

Use Unix format (`U`, the number of seconds since Unix era; use `@` to convert it back to date object) for date arithmetics.

Examples (assuming that you have the special property *[Creation date](https://www.semantic-mediawiki.org/wiki/Property:Creation_date)* activated):

```
<!-- Pages created today -->
{{#ask:
[[Creation date::>={{#time:d.m.Y}}]]
}}

<!-- Pages created yesterday -->
{{#ask:
[[Creation date::>={{#time:d xg Y|@{{#expr:{{#time:U}}-86400}}}}]]
[[Creation date::<{{#time:d xg Y}}]]
}}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can also use the MediaWiki magic words https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Help:Magic_words/de e.g.

```
{{#ask:
[[Modification date::>={{CURRENTYEAR}}-{{CURRENTMONTH}}-{{CURRENTDAY2}}]]
}}
```